# Jersey, return response to browser before hitting the resource

Tags: java, validation, parameters, jersey

I am using Jersey framework for my RESTful services.

Each of my resource class inherits a base class, I have few URL parameter validations in place inside my base class, so if I find that a mandatory field is missing in the URL, I want to stop the flow in my base class (i.e. Don't want to go and hit my resource method and return a response to browser from my base class).

Currently I am not able to do that and even if I try like for e.g do something like following to go back to browser with missing param message, it won't and still goes and hit the resource class web service method being called:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
               .entity("Parameter value missing for "+ StringHelper.ArrayToString(requiredParametersValueMissing))
               .build();
```

Any ideas or similar situation being faced by you guys. Input appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a WebApplicationException like so:

```
throw new javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException(javax.ws.rs.core.Response
.status(javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
.entity("Parameter value missing for ").type("text/html").build());
```

I handled what you're trying to do by extending com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer and parsing out the params myself from HttpServletRequest.  If I find an error I call

```
return super.service(baseUri, requestUri, request, response);
```

Is this what you're doing in your base class?

Comment: hi Chris, thanks ur answer is in the right direction, i tried the exception throwing, but on browser it shows up like :

Error creating bean with name 'customersWebService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException

it doesn't show our custom message i.e. the params missing or our own error code, yes i am trying to do what you did extending ServletContainer, I am also stripping off the request in my base class, if you could share your ServletContainer approach with code that'd be great.

Comment: I am interested to know how you extended the class and added it to framework so that the webrequests pass through them.
But i guess i tried the approach in the filter and my issue is that i am using custom annotations to mark the resource class parameters required in my resource classes and these annotations will not be available to me in a filter or servlet container extension class.

Comment: You need to specify your ServletContainer in web.xml, like so:     <servlet-class>com.tcore.tfs.adapters.rest.RestAdapterServletContainer</servlet-class>

Comment: Then, extend the ServletContainer (is there a better way to format code in comments?) `public class YourServletContainer extends com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
{
    @Override
    public int service(URI baseUri, URI requestUri, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        // extract parameters for logging
       boolean errorFromParams = parseParameters(request.getParameterMap());

       if (errorFromParams)
  return super.service(baseUri, requestUri, request, response); 
 } 
}`